# jsonify() and jsonify([]) returning different results in jQuery

Tags: jquery, python, flask, handlebars.js, typeahead

## Edit

typeahead assumes results retrieved from  your `source:` dataset are **arrays** (and parses them as such)

passing in a single JSONified dict{} raises an error by Typeahead.

[(see below)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48249026/7283224)

---

I am trying to parse a single dictionary (python) in a **Typeahead**'s `templates` option (js):

Imagine the dict looks like  `{"id": 1, "name": "us", "place": "idaho"}`

```
  // trying to parse a dict obj here
  templates: 
       {
       suggestion: Handlebars.compile("<div>+{{ key }}+</div>") 
       }
```

**1.**

dict passed as `flask.jsonify([dict])` -- {{ key }}  works.

dict passed as `flask.jsonify(dict)`    -- {{ this.key }} works, {{ key }} doesn't, how is jQuery accessing this dict?

**2.**

is this how the script runs?

```
(when a query ("#q") is typed)

  code

 (.js)                                    (.js)                                                 asyncResults(data) passed to            (.js)
    typeahead {source: func1(*kwargs)} ----> func1(query, syncResults, asyncResults): ------------------------------------------------> typeahead {suggestion: Handlebars.compile()}
              ＾calls function1                $.getJSON("/url", params, func2(data,textStatus,jqXHR))   (.py)                                     ＾uses asyncResults(data) as associated Suggestion object
                                                        ＾sends GET request to "/url" -----------------> function at ("/url")                         (i.e suggestion.data = whatever was returned from asyncResults()?)
                                                                ＾calls func2 on success <-------------  ＾return jsonify(result) as data
                                                                        ＾return asyncResults(data)       
                                                                                 [AsyncFunction object]
```

---

## Code:

#### script.js

```
function configure()
{
    $("#q").typeahead(

        // options
        {   highlight: false,
            minLength: 1
        },

        // *dataset
        {   display: function(suggestion) {return null;},
            limit: 10,
            source: search,
            templates: {
                suggestion: Handlebars.compile("<div>" + "{{ id }}" + "</div>");}
        }
     );
}

function search(query, syncResults, asyncResults)
{
    let params = { q: query };

    $.getJSON("/search",
                 params,
                 function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                         asyncResults(data);
                 }
              );
}
```

#### app.py

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, json, render_template, request
from sqlalchemy import *

@app.route("/search")
def search():
    if request.method == "GET":
        query = request.args.get("q")
        stmt = table.select().where(table.c.place_name.startswith(query))
        _result = dbsession.query(stmt).scalar()

        result = {}
        for _row in _result:
            for k,i in zip( _row.keys(), range(len(_row.keys())) ):
                result.setdefault(k, _row[i])

    return jsonify(result)
```

---

#### Troubleshooting

variables referred:

```
// from search() in "app.py"
result = {'id': 2, 'name': 'user', 'place': 'idaho'} 
<type 'dict'>

// from $("q").typeahead() from configure() in "script.js"
suggestion = Handlebars.compile("<div>" + "{{ id }}" + "</div>")

// from $.getJSON() from search() in "script.js"
data = [object Object]
(typeof data = object)
```

`search()` in **app.py**:

```
if jsonify(result)   // typeahead shows nothing (i.e suggestion not showing {{ id }} )
if jsonify([result]) // typeahead works (i.e suggestion shows {{ id }} )
```

`search()` in **script.js**:

```
 if jsonify(result)   // alert(data["key"]) shows key value
 if jsonify([result]) // alert(data[0]["key"]) shows key value

 alert(data)        // returns "[object Object]"
 alert(typeof data) // returns "object"
```

**docs referred:**

- [typeahead](https://github.com/corejavascript/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md) doc
- [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) doc
- [asyncFunction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/AsyncFunction) doc
- [flask.jsonify](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.json.jsonify) doc

Comment: Lots of your code contains notes interspersed with code, or syntactically invalid code. Also, your code consists of two parts here: One that downloads something via AJAX, and one that renders something via handlebars. With which of the two is your problem? Also, while it's generally great to include lots of code, I'm a little bit confused as to which part of the code does what. Is it possible to distill the question just down to one program section that fails? Code that works does not need to be mentioned at all.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, honestly unsure where the problem was so dumped everything haha. Will take some time to clean this up, hopefully I'll figure out the answer by then!

Answer (score 0):

oh wow. Solved!

typeahead parses your callback result (i.e. associated suggestion object) [as an **array**.](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/588440f66559714280628a4f9799f0c4eb880a4a/src/typeahead/dataset.js#L266)

Converting the dict to an array/ list before the callback makes everything work as intended.

either

```
if (!data.length){
     data = [data];}
asyncResults(data);
```

or

```
jsonify([dict])
```

---

#### [dataset.js from typeahead source](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/588440f66559714280628a4f9799f0c4eb880a4a/src/typeahead/dataset.js#L266)

```
function async(suggestions) {
suggestions = suggestions || [];

if (!canceled && rendered < that.limit) {
          that.cancel = $.noop;

          // dict.length is 'undefined'
          rendered += suggestions.length; 

          // and this would just raise an error (i.e. "suggestions.slice(..) is undefined")
          that._append(query, suggestions.slice(0, that.limit - rendered)); 

          that.async && that.trigger('asyncReceived', query);
}
```

thanks to [jFensch](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/741) for pointing that out